# How to get the details of apps installed in a device in my app

Tags: uiapplication, iphone-privateapi, uidevice

is there any way i can have an access to the name of applications that are installed in the current device in my app.  is there any api's to get hold of this.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not with documented methods. Why do you want to know what other apps the user has installed anyway?

---

With *undocumented* methods, you could use (usual warnings apply):

1. SpringBoardServices:

   - `SBSCopyApplicationDisplayIdentifiers(false, false);`
2. GraphicsServices:

   - `GSSystemCopyCapability(kGSApplicationInstallationCapability);`
3. liblockdown:

   - `... lockdown_copy_value(kLockdownNotificationApplicationInstalled); ...`